# Spring - beans lifecycle

Tags: java, spring

I have several configured beans in my spring application. All the beans working as it supposed to work and doing their jobs.

The thing is, I implemented a `BeanPostProcessor` and noticed that it isn't being called for some of the beans, (neither `postProcessAfterInitialization` nor `postProcessBeforeInitialization`). What could be the cause ?

Comment: do you mean that for some bean it is being called and for others it is not ?

Comment: yes , in fact almost all of the beans are being called except for several beans

Comment: How about posting the configuration for those beans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is relevant, but the reference manual says:

> **BeanPostProcessors and AOP auto-proxying**
>
> Classes that implement the BeanPostProcessor interface are special,
>   and so they are treated differently by the container. All
>   BeanPostProcessors and their directly referenced beans will be
>   instantiated on startup, as part of the special startup phase of the
>   ApplicationContext, then all those BeanPostProcessors will be
>   registered in a sorted fashion - and applied to all further beans.
>   Since AOP auto-proxying is implemented as a BeanPostProcessor itself,
>   no BeanPostProcessors or directly referenced beans are eligible for
>   auto-proxying (and thus will not have aspects 'woven' into them.
>
> For any such bean, you should see an info log message: “Bean 'foo' is
>   not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for
>   example: not eligible for auto-proxying)”.

So, maybe your beans are being proxied.

Comment: That's it!

Thanks for this comment. :)

I can see an info log with the message as you mentioned.